# How to `presentViewController` with custom animation on iOS 6?

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

How can I have custom animation for view controller presented with `presentViewController` method on iOS 6+ ? I want the new VC's view to zoom in from some point.

I'm using the following routine to fade in new controller:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

But I'm not sure how and whether it's possible to zoom in view this way.

Comment: Great Question, I'm looking for the same thing!